# How to have two mutually recursive struct types in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

The following code does not compile:

```
[<Struct>]
type Point(x:int, y:int) =
    member __.X = x
    member __.Y = y
    member __.Edges = ArrayList<Edge>()
[<Struct>]
and Edge(target:Point, cost:int) =
    member __.Target = target
    member __.Cost = cost
```

The problem resides on the `[<Struct>]` attributes, that seem to collide with the "and" construct.

How should I go about doing this? I know I could alternatively accomplish the task with

```
type Point(x:int, y:int) =
    struct
        member __.X = x
        member __.Y = y
        member __.Edges = new ArrayList<Edge>()
    end
and Edge(target:Point, cost:int) =
    struct
        member __.Target = target
        member __.Cost = cost
    end
```

but I like the `[<Struct>]` succinctness.

Thanks

Comment: This question also applies to `[<AllowNullLiteral>]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the attribute definition after the `and` token

```
and [<Struct>] Edge(target:Point, cost:int) =
```

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate Jared's answer:

per F# spec (8. Type Definitions)
*Custom attributes may be placed immediately before a type definition group, in which case they apply to the first type definition, or immediately before the name of the type definition*

meaning that you can also use this style:

```
type
    [<Struct>]
    A(x : int) = 
        member this.X = x
and
    [<Struct>]
    B(y : int) = 
        member this.Y = y
```